# Swift 2 - NSURLSession Not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to do NSURLSession call like so:

```
let requestString = NSString(format: "http://api.com/api/Action/?tag=%d", Int(barcode)!) as String
let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: requestString)

urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in

    do {        
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [AnyObject]    
        print(jsonData)

    } catch {


    }
}
```

My issue is that the code inside the `do` statement does not get executed, so the print statement does not get executed. I tried putting a `print("Error")` inside the `catch` statement and that does not even get executed. I am trying to do a synchronous NSURLSession call, what am I missing here?

Comment: You're trying to do a synchronous call using an asynchronous method

Comment: You also never call `resume()` on the task so it never runs

Comment: @dan then how do I do a synchronous call?

Comment: As @dan mentioned, you need to call resume as dataTaskWithURL only returns the task but won't execute it, you need to explicitly call resume on it.

Comment: @user979331 Don't try synchronous calls, learn to understand the asynchronous behavior of `dataTask...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call **resume** explicitly on returned dataTask to get it executed

```
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(...)
dataTask.resume
```