# URLSession.shared.upload works, URLSession.shared.uploadTask doesn't?

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm new-ish to Swift, and trying to send a JSON POST request to a rails server from a Swift MacOS app. The following works:

```
let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.upload(for: self.loginURLRequest,
 from: encodedLoginDetails, delegate: nil)
```

While this does not:

```
let response = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: self.loginURLRequest, from: encodedLoginDetails,
                                            completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                                              print("We got here")
                                            })
```

When I say "doesn't" work:

- The completionHandler is never entered
- Server logs for the receiving API server show no activity (whereas they show the correct response for the .upload request). By no activity: no error message, no malformed query message - nothing. It isn't being received
- Subsequent commands after .uploadTask are called successfully, no error throws in swift
- Printing "response" returns a LocalUploadTask with 0 bytes sent/received, -1byte  expected to send/receive
- The call is to a "localhost:3000" server. The server is definitely running and working fine receiving the same API call through other methods (.upload, or via postman)

I've been trying to understand how these two commands differ, and why the latter isn't working, but what I'm reading from Apple docs suggest there shouldn't be any functional difference for my purposes(?)

For reference, the data being sent is:

```
var loginRequest = URLRequest(url: loginURL)
loginRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
loginRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
loginRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
self.loginURLRequest = loginRequest

let encodedLoginDetails = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(username, forKey: .userId) 
}
```

Exact same data/request work fine with .upload. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 2 - NSURLSession Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400817/swift-2-nsurlsession-not-working). That question/answer is based on older Swift but the answer is basically the same.

Comment: If you read the Discussion section of the [documentation for uploadTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411518-uploadtask) it also points out what you need to do.

Comment: just to clarify for myself the latter explicitly requires `.resume` as in the regular `URLSession` calls right? The docs also say `After you create the task, you must start it by calling its resume() method.` And for the former, does not require the explicit `.resume` why? My guess would be it is the new feature of `URLSession` which works with async/await, is that so? @HangarRash

Comment: @Jokecoder `upload` doesn't require `resume()` because it doesn't return a task that must be resumed. The async/await design of `upload` doesn't have a completion handler and it directly returns the desired result.